# Android application access my server but got a timeout error

Tags: java, tomcat

My app client access my Tomcat. Some times it works well, but sometimes it times out - especially when two people quickly flush the frame to access the server. What might be the problem?

I can make sure that my database doesn't hang. Because I also have a management system on my Tomcat and they use the same database. The system works well even if my app can't access the server.

Answer (score 0):

First check your server tomcat running system configuration, like ram capacity and internet speed ect.. because it seems to be you are using same system for data base also.
Some time bad/ slow network connections in client side also will cause 
this kind of time out errors, So just add conn.setTimeout(60000) line in from your client code near http call.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. I'll follow your instruction to test my code.          But what if my server had no error log? Is that means my ram capacity have no problem?

Comment: If you are using data base also in the same server your ram capacity also need to check, before that check your tomcat connection pooling   http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-configuration-for-production-and-development/